# JavaScript Snake Game, not able to detect food and generate it

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I am trying to code Snake Game using JavaScript. For now, I am trying to make just the snake head collide with food and generate it elsewhere randomly when snake collides with it but that is not happening. Here is my code for main.js, snake.js and input.js:

main.js:

```
import Snake from "./snake.js"
import Food from "./food.js";

export var container = document.getElementById("gameBoard");
var ctx = container.getContext('2d');
var currentTime = 0;
export var gameW  = container.width;
export var gameH = container.height;

 let snake1 = new Snake(gameW,gameH);
 let food = new Food();

function gameLoop(){
  setTimeout(gameLoop, 50);
   ctx.clearRect(0,0,400,400);
   update();
  draw();
  
}
gameLoop(currentTime);

function update(){
    snake1.update();
   if(snake1.checkCollision()){
       food.spawn();
       food.draw(ctx);
   }
    

    if(snake1.checkDeath()){
        console.log('gameOver');
    }
   
}
function  draw(){
    
    snake1.draw(ctx);
     food.draw(ctx);
    
}
```

snake.js:

```
 import {getInputDirection} from "./input.js";
 import Food from "./food.js";
 let food = new Food();

export default class Snake{
        
     constructor(gameW,gameH){
        this.width = 10;
        this.height = 10;
        this.x = 0
        this.y = 0;
        this.body = [];
        this.pos = {
         x:gameW/2 - this.width,
         y:gameH/2 - this.height  
     };
     }
     
     update(){
          const inputS = getInputDirection();
    this.body.push(this.pos['x'],this.pos['y']);     
  this.pos['x'] += inputS.x;
  this.pos['y'] += inputS.y;
     }
     
     draw(ctx){
       ctx.fillStyle = "black";
       ctx.fillRect(this.pos['x'],this.pos['y'],this.width,this.height);
     }
     checkDeath(){
          if(this.pos['x'] < 0){
      return true;
    }
    else if(this.pos['x'] > 400){
        return true;
    }
     else if(this.pos['y'] > 400){
        return true;
    }
     else if(this.pos['y'] < 10){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
     }
     
      checkCollision(){
    var score = 0;
    if(this.x === food.x && this.y === food.y){ 
    score++;
    console.log(score);
    return true;
    }
    return false;
      }
     
}
```

food.js:

```
import {container,gameW, gameH} from "./main.js";

export default class Food{
    constructor(){
        this.width = 6;
        this.height = 6;
        this.spawn();
    }
    spawn(){
        this.x =  Math.floor(Math.random()*(gameW/10))*10;
        this.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*(gameH/10))*10 
}
    
    draw(ctx){
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
        }  
    }
```

input.js :

```
let speed = {
    x:0,
    y:0
};
let prevSpeed = {
    x:0,
    y:0
};

window.addEventListener('keydown',e =>{
  switch(e.key){
      case 'ArrowUp':
       if(prevSpeed.y !== 0) break;
       speed = {x:0,y:-1};
       break;
          
      case'ArrowDown':
       if(prevSpeed.y !== 0) break;
       speed = {x:0,y:1};
       break;
          
      case'ArrowLeft':
       if(prevSpeed.x !== 0) break;
       speed = {x:-1,y:0};
       break;
          
      case 'ArrowRight':
          if(prevSpeed.x !== 0) break;
       speed = {x:1,y:0};
       break;
  }  
});

export  function getInputDirection(){
    prevSpeed = speed;
    return speed;
}
```

For now, I can move the snake in different directions and when it hits the boundary, i get the console.log('game over').

Comment: instead of importing the game window size and container, pass them into the `food` class constructor, like you are doing with the snake.

Comment: Hey there,I tried doing that as well but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the fact that the food is placed in 10 pixel boundary and the snake moves in pixels. The food won't be collected unless you are perfectly aligned on the same 10 pixel boundary.

Also you use this.x here whereas you use this.pos.x for boundary collision.

If you change the following:

```
if(this.x === food.x && this.y === food.y){
```

to:

```
    if(Math.abs(this.pos.x - food.x) < food.width && Math.abs(this.pos.y - food.y) < food.height){
```

While this somewhat works, ideally you should get the player center point and food center point and do the collision from that rather than top left. To detect collision range it is (player width + food width) / 2.

You also declared food twice. Once in main.js and once in snake.js

delete this line from snake.js

```
let food = new Food();
```

```js
var container = document.getElementById("gameBoard");
var ctx = container.getContext('2d');
var currentTime = 0;

var gameW  = container.width;
var gameH = container.height;

function gameLoop(){
  setTimeout(gameLoop, 50);
   ctx.clearRect(0,0,400,400);
   update();
  draw();
  
}


function update(){
    snake1.update();
   if(snake1.checkCollision()){
       food.spawn();
       food.draw(ctx);
   }
    

    if(snake1.checkDeath()){
        console.log('gameOver');
    }
   
}
function  draw(){
    
    snake1.draw(ctx);
     food.draw(ctx);
    
}






class Snake{
        
     constructor(gameW,gameH){
        this.width = 10;
        this.height = 10;
        this.x = 0
        this.y = 0;
        this.body = [];
        this.pos = {
         x:gameW/2 - this.width,
         y:gameH/2 - this.height  
     };
     }
     
     update(){
          const inputS = getInputDirection();
    this.body.push(this.pos['x'],this.pos['y']);     
  this.pos['x'] += inputS.x;
  this.pos['y'] += inputS.y;
     }
     
     draw(ctx){
       ctx.fillStyle = "black";
       ctx.fillRect(this.pos['x'],this.pos['y'],this.width,this.height);
     }
     checkDeath(){
          if(this.pos['x'] < 0){
      return true;
    }
    else if(this.pos['x'] > 400){
        return true;
    }
     else if(this.pos['y'] > 400){
        return true;
    }
     else if(this.pos['y'] < 10){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
     }
     
      checkCollision(){
    var score = 0;
    if(Math.abs(this.pos.x - food.x) < food.width && Math.abs(this.pos.y - food.y) < food.height){ 
    score++;
    console.log(score);
    return true;
    }
    return false;
      }
     
}




class Food{
    constructor(){
        this.width = 6;
        this.height = 6;
        this.spawn();
    }
    spawn(){
        this.x =  Math.floor(Math.random()*(gameW/10))*10;
        this.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*(gameH/10))*10 
}
    
    draw(ctx){
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
        }  
    }


let speed = {
    x:0,
    y:0
};
let prevSpeed = {
    x:0,
    y:0
};

window.addEventListener('keydown',e =>{
  switch(e.key){
      case 'ArrowUp':
       if(prevSpeed.y !== 0) break;
       speed = {x:0,y:-1};
       break;
          
      case'ArrowDown':
       if(prevSpeed.y !== 0) break;
       speed = {x:0,y:1};
       break;
          
      case'ArrowLeft':
       if(prevSpeed.x !== 0) break;
       speed = {x:-1,y:0};
       break;
          
      case 'ArrowRight':
          if(prevSpeed.x !== 0) break;
       speed = {x:1,y:0};
       break;
  }  
});

function getInputDirection(){
    prevSpeed = speed;
    return speed;
}

 let snake1 = new Snake(gameW,gameH);
 let food = new Food();
gameLoop(currentTime);
```

```html
<canvas id="gameBoard" width="400"  height"400">
```

Comment: Hello John, Thank you for your reply. I ran the code snippet and it works but I had a question: If I remove the food = new Food() from snake.js file, how will it identify the food.x and food.y variable?

Comment: Actually , I have added parameters inside the checkcollision method which can then be passed into snake.js file’s checkcollision method and it works.